# TravisCI not receiving requests from private github repository

Tags: git, travis-ci

I was just configuring a private repository from my personal github into TravisCI.com (which allow me to trigger private builds), and despite the fact that I have correctly configured the .travis.yaml file, whenever I commit changes into my repository, Travis does not receive any request.

When I make the repository public, the push request is sent, the build is trigger and it passes without problems; but when I change it to a private repository, no request is received in Travis. Do I need to configure anything in Github or Travis? I had recently used it with a private forked repository without issue, so I am a bit baffled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you activate the repository? [Help page](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/tutorial/#to-get-started-with-travis-ci-using-github).

Comment: Yes I did, when I installed Travis as a github app. The thing is, it does work fine when the repo is public, but whenever I change it to private, it stops sending the commit hooks to Travis.